# Setting the maximum value that can be entered into a JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I have the following code which only allows one numerical value to allowed in the field:

```
try {
  MaskFormatter deckLevelEntry = new MaskFormatter("#");
  deckLevelEntry.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');

  deckLevelEntryField = new JFormattedTextField(deckLevelEntry);
  detailsPanel.add(deckLevelEntryField);
  wholeFramePanel.add(detailsPanel);
  frame3.add(wholeFramePanel);
  frame3.setVisible(true);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
```

However, is there a way, if so how, to set the maximum numerical value to be entered? by this I mean I want the following value's to be accepted in the `JFormattedTextField`: 1,2,3 and 4. Anything above 4 should not be allowed to entered. The same applies for the value of 0.

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` instead.

Comment: BTW - `} catch (Exception ex) { }` at least dump the stack trace.  I wish I had a dollar for every person that claimed their code 'runs without error' only to realize it has errors which are being entirely ignored.

Comment: *"1,2,3 and 4. Anything above 4 should not be allowed to entered. The same applies for the value of 0."* But for just 4 values it might be better represented in a `JList` or `JComboBox`.  Add a 5th saying `Select Dock` if you need to track that the user has actually *made a choice.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
NumberFormatter nf = new NumberFormatter();
nf.setMinimum(new Integer(30));
nf.setMaximum(new Integer(70));
final JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
```